# github actions publish fails - NPM ERR 404

Tags: github-actions, npm-publish

npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/mypkg - Not found

unable to publish via github actions, the build portion works fine

i am able to publish this locally from my local machine terminal. without any issue.

i attempted having macos for publish action as well no luck.

```
name: mypkg_npm

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-11.0
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12 
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm test    
      - run: npm run build

  publish-npm:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/ 
      - name: Setup GIT
        run: |
          git config user.email "myemail"
          git config user.name "vands"
      - run : npm version patch 
      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}}
```

Comment: Can you show your .npmrc file ? Have you you created the secret NPM_AUTH_TOKEN?

Comment: yes i have created the NPM_AUTH_TOKEN, where can i find nmprc?